# ngx uploader unable to upload cropped image on server - angular 6

Tags: file-upload, angular6, cropper, ngx-uploader

I'm cropping image before upload to server so integrated cropping module. I want to upload cropped image to server but `ngx uploader` uploading original image.

I have used `ngx-uploader ngx-uploader: "6.0.1"` and for cropper used `"ngx-image-cropper": 1.2.3.`

For uploader : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-uploader

For Cropper : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper

Following function get called on crop success.

```
startUpload(): void {
const event: UploadInput = {
type: 'uploadAll',
url: 'server path'
method: 'POST',
headers: 'custom header',
file: this.croppedImage,
};

this.uploadInput.emit(event);
}
```